# Make image overlap another

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get the look that I've drawn on my image but the ImageView hides behind the button so it's not visible. I've tried all Android commands I know but nothing seems to work.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/football"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/football_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/football"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Desired look:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **drawableLeft** in your Button so your xml would be like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/football_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/football"
    android:text="@string/football"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

Comment: While this is completely true, it should be noted that, while this is the easy way of doing it, you lose some of the positioning control when using this. I.e. I didn't use this in my project because I couldn't completely control the position of the drawable. If the OP needs advanced positioning of his items, he could be better-off just using a different layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ImageView to be next to the button you can add toRightOf to the button.

If you want the ImageView to be on top of the button, put Button before ImageView and add `android:elevation="2dp"` to the ImageView.